# Merge 2 SQL statements into 1?

Tags: mysql, php

Can anyone help me transforming these 2 SQL statements into 1?

```
$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT `UID` FROM `ratings`";
$query3 = "SELECT `RID`,`rating` FROM `ratings` WHERE `UID` = $uid";
```

original php code:

```
$arrayAux=array();
$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT `UID` FROM `ratings`";

$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

if(!$result2) return $arrayAux;

    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    $array2=array();
    $uid=$row2['UID'];

            $query3 = "SELECT `RID`,`rating` FROM `ratings` WHERE `UID` = $uid";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
            if(!$result3) return $arrayAux;
            while ($row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3,MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $rid=$row3['RID'];
                $rating=$row3['rating'];

                $array2[$rid] = $rating;
                }

    array_push($arrayAux, $array2);
        }
return $arrayAux;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I fail to see the reason for two queries. What's wrong with `select uid, rid, rating from ratings`?

Comment: It is rather about the formatting of the output. SO i want an array consisting of "users" holding an array of RID and ratings. so raffeales' answer seems intuitive (group by) but does not do the trick..

Answer (score -2):

select rid,rating,uid from ratings group by uid;

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/